# Nested bean property, Exception: Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null

Tags: jsf, el

In a OneToOne relationship,I Can't persist The fields of Adresse but I get no error for School fields it's give this error:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /inscription/school-inscription.xhtml @29,91 value="#{createBn.school.adresse.country}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
```

here is the view:

```
<h:inputText id="name" value="#{createBn.school.name}" pt:placeholder="ex: Dalton" />

<h:inputText value="#{createBn.school.creationDate}" pt:placeholder="31-12-2000" />

<h:selectOneMenu value="#{createBn.school.adresse.country}" styleClass="form-control">
    <f:selectItems value="#{countriesList.countries}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>.....
```

so createBn:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class CreateBn implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private School school;

@EJB
private SchoolPr schoolPr;

public CreateBn(){
    user = new User();
    school = new School();
}

public void createSchool(){
    schoolPr.createSchool(school);
}
```

and here are the School Entity and the Adress Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "school", name = "school")
public class School implements Serializable {
....
private String name;

@OneToOne @JoinColumn(name = "adressId")
private Adresse adresse;
//getters +setters
```

Adress:

```
@Entity
@Table(schema = "school", name = "adress")
class Adresse implements java.io.Serializable {
..
private String country;
//getters +setters
```

Ps: I already see similar cases here but nothing helps + I delete most of the code posted here like ID fields and so, all getters and setters are implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `value="#{createBn.school.adresse.country}"`: Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null

This means that one of the following values is `null`:

- `#{createBn}`
- `#{createBn.school}`
- `#{createBn.school.adresse}`

The `createBn` looks okay at first sight (otherwise you'd have other problems as well). The `school` looks okay as you explicitly created it with `new School()`. However, I'm not seeing that for `adresse` anywhere. Fix it accordingly.

```
school.setAdresse(new Adresse());
```